# Freeing memory by using free() whoes pointer is inside a pointer pointing to structure

Tags: c, pointers

Hey!
I know title of question is very scary but I still I am not able to express the problem in single line!

So Here I go:

There is a Data Pointer say DataPtr which is pointing to a dynamically allocated memory and Another Structure Pointer say StructPtr which also points to a Dynamically allocated structure.

And These both are in another structure,say OuterStructure.

There is a Linked List which contains Pointer to OuterStructure.

```
struct StructONE
{
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
};

struct InnerStruct
{
  char a;
  int b;
};

struct StructTWO
{
   int Num;
   char * DataPtr;
   struct InnerStruct * StructPtr;  
};

struct LinkList
 {
   int NodeNum;
   int NodeType;       /* To Indicate Whether Pointer is of StructOne or StructTwo */  
   void * Ptr;        /* This can be of type StructONE or StructTWO */
   struct LinkList * Next;

 };

LinkList * Start;
void main()
{

  /* Structure Declarations */
    InnerStruct * InnerStructure;
    StructONE * OneStruct;
    StructTWO * TwoStruct;

 /* Fill up all the Structure */
     InnerStructure= (InnerStruct *)calloc(100,sizeof(InnerStruct));
     InnerStructure->a='a';
     InnerStructure->b=5;

  OneStruct= (StructONE *)calloc(100,sizeof(StructONE));
  TwoStruct= (StructTWO *)calloc(100,sizeof(StructTWO));

  TwoStruct->Dataptr=(char *) calloc(10,sizeof(char));
  TwoStruct->StructPtr= InnerStructure;



 /* Add these to Linked List
   void Add_to_Linked_List(int NodeNum,int NodeType,void *ptr)
 */
   Add_to_Linked_List(1,1,OneStruct);
   Add_to_Linked_List(2,2,TwoStruct);

/* Everything is Okey Till Here.
   Now When I want to delete a node from linked list,
   First I have to release Memory pointed by DataPtr and StructPtr. */

  DeleteNode(1);

} /* End of Main */
```

The Code for DeleteNode is like this:

```
void DeleteNode(int Num)
{
  LinkList * NodePtr,*TempNode;
NodePtr= Start;

  while(NodePtr->NodeNum!=Num)
      NodePtr=NodePtr->Next;

  /* Now NodePtr points to desired node */
   if(NodePtr->NodeType==1) /* Pointer is StructONE Type */
     {
        free(NodePtr->Ptr);
        TempNode->Next=NodePtr->Next;
        free(NodePtr);
        return;
     }
    else
     {
        /* Now the Problem Begins.... 
           In StructTWO type, I have to release Memory allocated for DataPtr as well Struct Ptr */
        free((NodePtr->ptr)->DataPtr);   
/* This Line Generates Error as
  Error C2227: left of '->DataPtr' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    */


     }


}
```

What Should I do??

I know I have written code terribly... but Have to write this much complex!! 
:(

Thank you for reading this as well!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define STRUCT_ONE 1
#define STRUCT_TWO 2

struct LinkList
 {
   int NodeNum;
   int NodeType;
   union 
    {
      StructONE * Ptr_One;
      StructTWO * Ptr_Two;
    };

 };

................

   if(NodePtr->NodeType==STRUCT_ONE)
     {
        free(NodePtr->Ptr_One);
        TempNode->Next=NodePtr->Next;
        free(NodePtr);
        return;
     }
    else
     {
        free(NodePtr->Ptr_Two->DataPtr);   
        ....
     }
```

Comment: This is also a great Way!! Thank You Rosh!!

Answer (score 3):

```
free((NodePtr->ptr)->DataPtr);
```

first of all, it is true that your code is awful. Second, you don't have a `ptr` member. You have a `Ptr` member. And the latter is void*, so if you want to get `DataPtr` out of it, you should use a cast

```
free(((struct StructTwo*)(NodePtr->Ptr))->DataPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! And I am sorry for making you read such a dangerous code! :(

Comment: and "ptr" issue was just a typo on StackOverflow not in Original code!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to the correct type

```
/* I like parenthesis :-) */
((struct StructTwo *)(NodePtr->ptr))->DataPtr
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast :

```
if(NodePtr->NodeType==1) /* Pointer is StructONE Type */
 {
      ....
 }
else
 {
     struct StructTwo * s2ptr;
     s2ptr = (struct StructTwo *)NodePtr->ptr;
     free(s2ptr->DataPtr);
     free(s2ptr->StructPtr);
     free(NodePtr);
  }
```

If you use the pointer more than once, declaring a variable to hold it avoids to do the type casting on each line.